# I can't add CSS with functions.php

Tags: functions, theme-development, wp-enqueue-style, css, wp-register-style

I'm relatively new to creating a theme with WordPress, and I've been adding all the stylesheets (main and for each page) with the old `echo get_stylesheet_uri();`. But I find out that this isn't the recommended way to do, and instead, to add all the styles within functions.php.

Old method (working):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>">
```

New method (not working):

```
<?php
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');   //Posts thumbnails

    //Custom excerpt
    function get_excerpt($excerpt, $length, $more_char = '...'){
        return mb_strimwidth($excerpt, 0, $length, $more_char);
    }

    function theme_styles() {
        //METHOD 1
        //wp_register_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style');

        //METHOD 2
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
?>
```

I tried both methods above and none worked. Is there anything wrong besides my bad English?

---

**Edit (SOLVED)**

Thanks to [Nathan Johnson](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/106269/nathan-johnson) who found the error. I wasn't using `wp_head()` on my `header.php`, therefore, WordPress wasn't finding where to put the enqueue style. Rookie error.

Comment: Is this a child theme?

Comment: @kero No, it's the main theme.

Comment: Try `wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`

Comment: Do you use `wp_head()`?

Comment: @NathanJohnson found the error, I didn't know about `wp_head();`. Sorry to all.

Comment: Please post the solution as answer, you or @NathanJohnson – because this is how this site is supposed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding any file you must seperate your `header.php` file & add `wp_head()` function in `header.php` file

```
    // Load the theme stylesheets
    function theme_styles()  
    { 
        // Example of loading a custom css file for homepage just on the homepage
        wp_register_style( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
        if(is_page('home')) {
            wp_enqueue_style('custom');
        }
        // Example of loading a main css file on all pages
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );

        // Example of loading js files on all pages
        wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js');
    
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

In this case the js files will be loaded on inside the `<head></head>` tag. If you want to load the js files in ths bottom you must need to add `<?php wp_footer() ?>` on your footer. And then you need to call the `wp_enqueue_script()` this way.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js','','1.1', true);
```

This `true` boolean is the answer of the `$in_footer` parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()` function. ( [See Doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#scripts) )

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-slug', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

Building a WordPress theme always use unique theme prefix for everything including function, class, constants, option etc.

Also, read the theme development documentation on wp.org

See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/

**Updated (27-Feb-2018)** Use unique prefix for your theme/plugin which avoid the conflict in between other theme/plugin.

Comment: Having a prefix is good practice, because it avoids conflict, but it is absolutely not a technical requirement that would stop this working. You can technically call the stylesheet whatever you want, and WordPress doesn't register any bundled stylesheets that are called 'main-style' that would cause conflicts.

Comment: Right, WordPress does not use prefix 'main-style' in the core. But, Other plugin/theme developers will use this common prefix (by mistake) for there scripts.